# What do you call the adjectives between transitive verbs and objects?

Tags: adjectives, adjuncts

> I carefully pried open her mouth. (The Weed that Strings the Hangman’s
>   Bag)

When intransitive verbs are followed by adjectives, they seem to call these adjectives as subjective complements or adjuncts. But the example has transitive verb [pried] before an adjective [open]. In this case, does this adjective be called an adjunct?

Comment: First, forget everything you've learned about "adjectives"; it is, regrettably, apparently, completely wrong. Next, look up the term [phrasal verb](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAPhrasalVerb.htm); _look up_ and _pry open_ are phrasal verbs. Any English word can be many different things; _open_ is a verb and an adjective and a phrasal verb particle, and it can appear in many constructions. Don't use the term _adjunct_ at all.

Comment: Conventional grammar calls it an *object complement* here ("a complement (belonging) to the object"). *I pried it open. I pried it half-open. I pried it loose* — The adjective can be replaced with other adjectives, and it describes a property of the object. Since it cannot be left out without messing up the core of the sentence, I would call it a *complement* to the verb, not an adjunct. It is of the same pattern as *I cut her loose, I called her brave, I painted her blue, I found her charming,* etc. etc. Needless to say, I and many others with me disagree with Lawler's approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is often debate about the 'unitariness' or otherwise of some of these structures. In

The aeroplane took off.

and

He took off (= impersonated) Groucho Marx. ,

there is little argument over the fact that 'take off' is behaving as a single verb. Though some people prefer not to use the term 'multi-word verb' here.

However, with

He took off his coat / He took his coat off, there seems more of an argument for verb and adverb (or intransitive preposition) - two components rather than one.

Again, contrast

He looked up the answer.

with

He looked up the hill.

Now, I'd say that with:

I carefully pried open her mouth. / I carefully pried her mouth open. ,

we're somewhere in the grey area

pry open = MWV?

pry = verb; open = adverb?

Certainly, the pretty comprehensive 'Oxford Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs' doesn't include *pry open*.

In the structure shown by

He went unarmed. ,

unarmed is a predicative adjective, coming after the linking verb.

in the similar structure shown by

He hammered the metal flat. ,

*hammer* is a transitive verb still able to fulfil a linking role. This type of structure is often described as secondary predication though Cobuild just labels the adjective (*flat* here) an object complement.

In *she left the door open*, open is indisputably an adjective.

In *she forced the door open*, I think most people would again accept open as an adjective.

In she *pried open the door*, I think it's sensible to accept the same analysis.

Comment: [Particle Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_(linguistics)) operates with real [phrasal verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Englishphrasalverbs.pdf), as distinguishable from transitivizing prepositions, like _look at, listen to, think about_.

Answer (score 2):

Conventional grammar calls it an **object complement** here ("a complement (belonging) to the object").

> I pried it open.
>
> I pried it half-open.
>
> I pried it loose.

The adjective *open* can be replaced with other adjectives, and it describes a (resultative) property of the object; it is therefore an object complement. It is of the same pattern as *I cut her loose, I called her brave, I painted her blue, I found her charming,* etc. etc. Object complements are often, but not always, resultative, in that they describe a property of the object after the action has taken place. It becomes open *after* the action of *prying*. The same applies to several kinds of subject complements, as in *I became angry, I turned red, I waxed poetic*.

Since it cannot be left out without messing up the core of the sentence, I would call it a **complement** to the verb, not an adjunct. I (and many others with me) clearly disagree with Lawler's approach.